# Cannot get Attributes from XML-file with custom namespace

Tags: php, xml

I have the following XML-Structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<psc:chapters version="1.2" xmlns:psc="http://podlove.org/simple-chapters">
    <psc:chapter start="00:00:12.135" title="Begrüßung" />
    <psc:chapter start="00:00:20.135" title="Faktencheck: Keine Werftführungen vor 2017"  />
    <psc:chapter start="00:02:12.135" title="Sea Life Timmendorfer Strand"" />
```

I need to get the title and start attribute. 
I already managed to get to the elements:

```
$feed_url="http://example.com/feed.psc";
$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$chapters=$x->children('psc', true);

foreach ($chapters as $chapter) {
    $unter=$chapter->children();
    print_r($unter);
}
```

The output is something like:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [start] => 00:00:12.135
            [title] => Begrüßung
        )    
)
```

When I now follow the answers here on SO to multiple questions to get the @attributes:

```
echo $unter->attributes()["start"];
```

I just receive an empty result.

(Update)
`print_r($unter->attributes())` returns an empty object:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

Comment: You already got the right answer, but to clarify: The attributes are not in a namespace - only attributes with a prefix can be in a namespace (unlike element nodes). Additionally I suggest using the actual namespace, not the alias/prefix: `$x->children('http://podlove.org/simple-chapters');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your attributes from chapter.

```
foreach ($chapters as $chapter) {
    // You can directly read them 
    echo $chapter->attributes()->{'title'}

    // or you can loop them
    foreach ($chapter->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . " : " . $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xml format was wrong (ending chapters tag). I modified your xml and php codes (reading chapter tag) like following format. Now its working perfect!

XML String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psc:chapters xmlns:psc="http://podlove.org/simple-chapters" version="1.2">
   <psc:chapter start="00:00:12.135" title="Begrüßung" />
   <psc:chapter start="00:00:20.135" title="Faktencheck: Keine Werftführungen vor 2017" />
   <psc:chapter start="00:02:12.135" title="Sea Life Timmendorfer Strand" />
</psc:chapters>
```

PHP Codes:

```
$x = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
$chapters=$x->children('psc', true);

foreach ($chapters->chapter as $chapter) {
    echo $chapter->attributes()->{'start'};
}
```

Comment: The missing closing tag was just my mistake here, because I did not want to paste the whole 100 lines of the xml here. Your code was right, though, i simply used the wrong object ($unter instead of $chapter) like mim found out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the element like an object, not an array:

```
echo $unter->attributes()->start;
```

More info in: http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes

Comment: Did not work either. $unter->attributes() seems to be an empty object